# Constructing a URL with parameters using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have for example the following URL stored in a global variable:

```
var myUrl = "http://mydomain.com/something?row=1";
```

Then a function has to add let's say another parameter called "*column*". How would that function add parameters to a pre-existing URL string using jQuery?

Example of the expected generated string:

```
"http://mydomain.com/something?row=1&column=9"
```

The problem is that `myUrl` could also be just:

```
var myUrl = "http://mydomain.com/something";
```

(Notice that there are not pre-existing parameters)

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: There is a component that needs that URL and has it's own way to fetch data using AJAX.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Check out the jQuery function .param(), that should do the trick.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

You can then just create a function which appends the string generated by .param() to a url.

Comment: What happens if the string already has parameters? Or the string already has parameters with the same name?

Comment: In that case the best thing is probably to parse the URL up front, then rebuild it later with jQuery.param or similar.

"The string is a stark data structure..."

Answer (score 25):

```
var myUrl = "http://mydomain.com/something";

function addQSParm(name, value) {
    var re = new RegExp("([?&]" + name + "=)[^&]+", "");

    function add(sep) {
        myUrl += sep + name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
    }

    function change() {
        myUrl = myUrl.replace(re, "$1" + encodeURIComponent(value));
    }
    if (myUrl.indexOf("?") === -1) {
        add("?");
    } else {
        if (re.test(myUrl)) {
            change();
        } else {
            add("&");
        }
    }
}

console.log(myUrl);

addQSParm("foo", "asdf");
console.log(myUrl);

addQSParm("bar", "qwerty");
console.log(myUrl);

addQSParm("foo", "123");
console.log(myUrl);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bYMVw/)

Comment: Using the regex `([?&]" + name + "=)([^&]+)?` will work better. This enables finding empty parameters within a URL.

Answer (score 21):

You don't need jQuery, use a function like this:

```
var buildUrl = function(base, key, value) {
    var sep = (base.indexOf('?') > -1) ? '&' : '?';
    return base + sep + key + '=' + value;
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
buildUrl('http://www.example.com/foo', 'test', '123');
buildUrl('http://www.example.com/foo?bar=baz', 'test', '123');
```

Comment: This does not take into account that the parameter could already exist. It would be obvious when you invoke it the way you do in the examples, but it would not be obvious when you add parameters to the URL when all the parameters come from other variables.

Comment: This is missing URL encoding.

Answer (score 4):

Keep everything in an object until you actually need a string.

First populate the object from some initial values:

```
var $_GET = location.search.substr(1).split("&").reduce( function( obj, val ){
    if( !val ) return obj;
    var pair = val.split("=");
    obj[pair[0]] = pair[1];
    return obj;
}, {} );
```

Considering initial url of: `"http://mydomain.com/something?row=1&column=9"`

```
$_GET['column'] = 5;

$.param( $_GET ); //"row=1&column=5"
```

[Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this.

```
myUrl += ((myUrl.indexOf('?') == -1) ? '?' : '&');
myUrl += "column=9";
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if (myUrl.indexOf("?") != -1){
    // contains query string
}
else
{
    // doesn't
}
```

Comment: This question asks about constructing the query string, not reading it.

Comment: I don't think you read the question. It's about detecting query string parameters.