# Can I apply a second query component for filtering WITHOUT using radio buttons?

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I've created filters that fetch either posts from today, this week or this month. This is easy and all, however, when I tried adding functionality that allows me to add a second filter, everything started going wrong.

First and foremost, I can't figure out how to append the second query component to the URL without using radio buttons. Currently I have this:

```
<ul class='home-filters'>
    <li><a class='placeholderA' href='?time=today'>Today</a></li>
    <li><a class='placeholderA' href='?time=week'>This Week</a></li>
    <li><a class='placeholderA' href='?time=month'>This Month</a></li>
    <li><a class='placeholderA' href='/'>Reset</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I click on any of these links, it appends the ?time= and the desired time frame to the URL like this `http://example.com/?time=month`. After that, my page controller determines which images to show using this code:

```
public function index(Request $request){

        if ($request->get('time') && $request->get('time') == 'today') {
            $images = Image::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                            ->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())
                            ->get();
        } else if ($request->get('time') && $request->get('time') == 'week') {
            $images = Image::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                            ->whereDate('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subWeek())
                            ->get();
        } else if ($request->get('time') && $request->get('time') == 'month') {
            $images = Image::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                            ->whereDate('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subMonth())
                            ->get();
        } else {
            $images = Image::orderBy('created_at', $request->get('order') ?? 'desc')
                            ->get();
        }

        return view('home', ['images' => $images]);
    }
```

This works all fine and dandy, however, I wanna make it so that I can apply 2 filters like this `http://example.com/?time=month&order=ascending`.

I'm trying to make it similarly to how it's done on this website - `https://www.artstation.com/` . If I select "Digital 2D" from the "All Media" dropdown menu and also click "Trending", the URL of the side becomes `https://www.artstation.com/artwork?sorting=trending&medium=digital2d`. Both the places on which I click seem to be `<a>` elements just like mine.

My goal is to be able to keep appending query components with a single click of an `<a>` element. I'll worry about dealing with the back-end logic after I figure out that.

Comment: Why don't you want to use radio buttons? You could also use a select list/checkboxes or what ever you like. Just create a form that uses GET and and how many filters you want. When you submit the form, you will get all the filters.

Comment: I want the page to refresh and and have visible change after every click. You click the first filter, the page refreshes and you get posts from today, you click a second filter, the page refreshes again and you get posts that meet both filters. If I were using a radio buttons, you'd have to select the first filter and nothing would happen, then select the second one and nothing would happen again and so on and so forth until the user has selected all filters and clicks submit to the form. Also I'd have to really work hard to change the look of radio buttons to something appealing.

Comment: You need some js to build your query string from various page elements and submit them in the built URL or ajax request. Parse the existing url params into a js object and then rebuild it when a filter is clicked or changed.  [Something like this ancient answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8902429/3585500)